# In UiPath, using Invoke code activity I am trying to get files in a folder which are updated or modified in last 24hrs

Tags: .net, vb.net, rpa, uipath, uipath-studio

These are the codes that I have tried

```vb
Dim myDirectory As new.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\MyFolder") 

Dim myFiles() As String = myDirectory.GetFiles.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.LastWriteTime).Select(Function(x) x.FullName).Take(40).ToArray

MsgBox(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, myFiles)
```

Here since I am giving Take(40), it will be taking only last 40files, but I want which can take all files which are modifies in last 24hrs(it may be 100 or 1000)

Comment: Doesn't look like VBScript more like VB.Net judging by the Linq syntax.

Comment: yes its vb.net, In UiPath we can use vb.net or c# for invoke code activity

Comment: Remove the Take(40), that will return you all files, then Function(x) x.LastWriteTime >= Date.Now.AddDays(-1).

Comment: Dim myDirectory As new.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\MyFolder") 

Dim myFiles() As String = myDirectory.GetFiles.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.LastWriteTime>= Date.Now.AddDays(-1)).Select(Function(x) x.FullName).ToArray

MsgBox(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, myFiles)      -  @Hursey I tried the way u told, I am getting all the files present in that folder not the files which are created/modified in 24hrs, I want files only which are created/updated in last 24hrs

Comment: Can you please tell me how to move those current files from one folder to other folder, I used copy folder of studiox activity , but it is taking whole folder not only the last 24hrs created/modified files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find all the files that were modified in the last 24 hours you can use a StudioX activity to loop through each file and then use the LastModifiedDate method to find the data they were modified.

First, you will need to click **Show StudioX** activities in the Activities window filter.

[image]

Then, select the **For Each File in Folder** activity.

[image]

After that, use this formula in the If activity: **Convert.ToDateTime(CurrentFile.LastModifiedDate()) > Now.AddDays(-1)**

[image]

In this example, the name of any file that was modified in the last 24 hours will show up in a message box.

Comment: Sure thing, be sure to look through more of those StudioX activities. I think you'll find more things to help you in your projects.

Comment: yeah sure I am new to Uipath, I'll definitely explore

Comment: Can you please tell me how to move those current files from one folder to other folder, I used copy folder of studiox activity , but it is taking whole folder not only the last 24hrs created/modified files.

Comment: You can replace the Message Box activity in my example with the Move File activity from StudioX.

Comment: I cannot find move file activity in studiox, I have move folder activity and when I used that it is taking all the files in the folder but not the latest/modified CurrentFile . And my requirement is to copy CurrentFiles from one folder to another.

Comment: Try updating your packages. On the Design tab, you should see the Manage Packages button. After updating, search for the Move File activity.

Comment: Can you please look into "How to copy multiple files which are created or modified in last 24hrs from one folder to another folder in UI Path?" this question, I have attached the screenshots as well